# Why are the lines generated by the \qbezier command not smooth (except for the horizontal and vertical ones, which are fine)?

Tags: diagrams

The following code is generated by Maple. I found that among the edges created by the `\qbezier` command, only the vertical and horizontal lines are smooth, while the others are not.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(300,300)
\thicklines
\linethickness{1pt}
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(60.78,187.36)(62.00,197.59)(63.22,207.82)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(60.78,187.36)(54.80,168.00)(48.83,148.65)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(60.78,187.36)(73.15,192.54)(85.53,197.72)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(63.22,207.82)(47.73,191.76)(32.23,175.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(63.22,207.82)(87.29,226.23)(111.36,244.64)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(32.23,175.70)(35.77,153.14)(39.31,130.58)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(32.23,175.70)(22.11,179.19)(12.00,182.69)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(39.31,130.58)(44.07,139.61)(48.83,148.65)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(39.31,130.58)(48.50,100.82)(57.70,71.07)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(48.83,148.65)(55.94,136.80)(63.05,124.95)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(85.53,197.72)(88.84,186.06)(92.14,174.39)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(85.53,197.72)(99.57,208.45)(113.61,219.19)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(92.14,174.39)(105.40,177.59)(118.67,180.79)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(92.14,174.39)(86.77,157.04)(81.41,139.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(118.67,180.79)(125.67,193.07)(132.67,205.34)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(118.67,180.79)(127.26,168.36)(135.85,155.92)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(132.67,205.34)(123.14,212.26)(113.61,219.19)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(132.67,205.34)(150.02,205.34)(167.36,205.33)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(113.61,219.19)(122.13,229.93)(130.66,240.67)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(111.36,244.64)(121.01,242.65)(130.66,240.67)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(111.36,244.64)(130.69,255.12)(150.01,265.60)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(130.66,240.67)(150.02,240.69)(169.38,240.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(169.38,240.70)(179.02,242.67)(188.65,244.64)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(169.38,240.70)(177.90,229.93)(186.42,219.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(188.65,244.64)(169.33,255.12)(150.01,265.60)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(188.65,244.64)(212.73,226.24)(236.81,207.84)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(150.01,265.60)(150.01,276.80)(150.01,288.00)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(12.00,182.69)(81.01,235.34)(150.01,288.00)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(12.00,182.69)(38.30,97.38)(64.60,12.07)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(150.01,288.00)(219.01,235.31)(288.00,182.62)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(288.00,182.62)(261.64,97.31)(235.28,12.00)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(288.00,182.62)(277.86,179.15)(267.71,175.68)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(235.28,12.00)(149.94,12.03)(64.60,12.07)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(235.28,12.00)(229.01,21.08)(222.75,30.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(64.60,12.07)(70.89,21.13)(77.19,30.19)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(57.70,71.07)(67.44,50.63)(77.19,30.19)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(57.70,71.07)(66.60,66.68)(75.50,62.30)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(77.19,30.19)(98.69,26.73)(120.20,23.27)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(120.20,23.27)(113.49,30.80)(106.79,38.34)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(120.20,23.27)(149.97,23.26)(179.74,23.25)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(106.79,38.34)(91.14,50.32)(75.50,62.30)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(106.79,38.34)(119.71,41.77)(132.62,45.21)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(75.50,62.30)(74.59,76.25)(73.69,90.21)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(63.05,124.95)(68.37,107.58)(73.69,90.21)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(63.05,124.95)(72.23,132.33)(81.41,139.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(73.69,90.21)(85.28,89.91)(96.87,89.61)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(96.87,89.61)(98.08,103.86)(99.29,118.11)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(96.87,89.61)(110.90,78.88)(124.94,68.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(99.29,118.11)(90.35,128.90)(81.41,139.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(99.29,118.11)(113.19,122.85)(127.09,127.59)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(226.27,90.19)(214.69,89.89)(203.12,89.59)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(226.27,90.19)(231.63,107.54)(237.00,124.90)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(226.27,90.19)(225.39,76.22)(224.51,62.25)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(203.12,89.59)(201.93,103.84)(200.73,118.10)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(203.12,89.59)(189.08,78.87)(175.04,68.15)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(200.73,118.10)(209.67,128.89)(218.61,139.68)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(200.73,118.10)(186.83,122.84)(172.93,127.59)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(218.61,139.68)(227.80,132.29)(237.00,124.90)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(218.61,139.68)(213.25,157.03)(207.89,174.38)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(237.00,124.90)(244.10,136.75)(251.21,148.61)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(224.51,62.25)(233.40,66.63)(242.30,71.02)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(224.51,62.25)(208.83,50.28)(193.16,38.32)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(242.30,71.02)(232.52,50.59)(222.75,30.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(242.30,71.02)(251.50,100.78)(260.70,130.54)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(222.75,30.16)(201.24,26.70)(179.74,23.25)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(179.74,23.25)(186.45,30.79)(193.16,38.32)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(193.16,38.32)(180.25,41.76)(167.34,45.20)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(175.04,68.15)(171.19,56.67)(167.34,45.20)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(175.04,68.15)(162.51,73.75)(149.99,79.36)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(167.34,45.20)(149.98,45.20)(132.62,45.21)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(132.62,45.21)(128.78,56.68)(124.94,68.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(124.94,68.16)(137.46,73.76)(149.99,79.36)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(149.99,79.36)(150.00,94.72)(150.01,110.09)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(172.93,127.59)(161.47,118.84)(150.01,110.09)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(172.93,127.59)(168.55,141.75)(164.18,155.91)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(150.01,110.09)(138.55,118.84)(127.09,127.59)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(127.09,127.59)(131.47,141.76)(135.85,155.92)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(135.85,155.92)(150.01,155.92)(164.18,155.91)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(164.18,155.91)(172.77,168.35)(181.36,180.78)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(207.89,174.38)(194.63,177.58)(181.36,180.78)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(207.89,174.38)(211.20,186.04)(214.50,197.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(181.36,180.78)(174.36,193.06)(167.36,205.33)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(167.36,205.33)(176.89,212.25)(186.42,219.16)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(186.42,219.16)(200.46,208.43)(214.50,197.70)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(214.50,197.70)(226.87,192.52)(239.25,187.33)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(251.21,148.61)(245.23,167.97)(239.25,187.33)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(251.21,148.61)(255.95,139.57)(260.70,130.54)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(239.25,187.33)(238.03,197.58)(236.81,207.84)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(236.81,207.84)(252.26,191.76)(267.71,175.68)
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(267.71,175.68)(264.21,153.11)(260.70,130.54)
\put(60.78,187.36){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(60.78,187.36){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(51.975,189.225){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){1}}
\put(63.22,207.82){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(63.22,207.82){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(57.235,214.537){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){2}}
\put(32.23,175.70){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(32.23,175.70){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(40.810,172.987){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){3}}
\put(39.31,130.58){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(39.31,130.58){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(30.540,128.544){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){4}}
\put(48.83,148.65){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(48.83,148.65){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(40.514,152.089){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){5}}
\put(85.53,197.72){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(85.53,197.72){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(81.022,205.510){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){6}}
\put(92.14,174.39){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(92.14,174.39){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(83.143,174.498){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){7}}
\put(118.67,180.79){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(118.67,180.79){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(113.258,187.989){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){8}}
\put(132.67,205.34){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(132.67,205.34){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(135.453,213.897){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){9}}
\put(113.61,219.19){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(113.61,219.19){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(107.301,225.608){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){10}}
\put(111.36,244.64){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(111.36,244.64){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(106.470,252.189){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){11}}
\put(130.66,240.67){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(130.66,240.67){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(131.568,249.628){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){12}}
\put(169.38,240.70){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(169.38,240.70){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(168.474,249.657){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){13}}
\put(188.65,244.64){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(188.65,244.64){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(193.545,252.199){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){14}}
\put(150.01,265.60){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(150.01,265.60){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(150.014,256.597){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){15}}
\put(12.00,182.69){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(12.00,182.69){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(3.429,185.431){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){16}}
\put(150.01,288.00){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(150.01,288.00){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(150.012,297.000){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){17}}
\put(288.00,182.62){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(288.00,182.62){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(296.572,185.362){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){18}}
\put(235.28,12.00){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(235.28,12.00){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(240.619,4.756){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){19}}
\put(64.60,12.07){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(64.60,12.07){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(59.255,4.828){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){20}}
\put(57.70,71.07){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(57.70,71.07){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(49.318,67.799){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){21}}
\put(77.19,30.19){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(77.19,30.19){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(82.580,37.392){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){22}}
\put(120.20,23.27){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(120.20,23.27){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(119.480,14.300){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){23}}
\put(106.79,38.34){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(106.79,38.34){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(100.665,31.745){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){24}}
\put(75.50,62.30){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(75.50,62.30){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(70.749,54.652){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){25}}
\put(63.05,124.95){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(63.05,124.95){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(54.826,121.295){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){26}}
\put(73.69,90.21){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(73.69,90.21){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(64.838,88.591){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){27}}
\put(96.87,89.61){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(96.87,89.61){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(93.873,81.124){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){28}}
\put(99.29,118.11){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(99.29,118.11){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(90.697,115.418){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){29}}
\put(81.41,139.70){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(81.41,139.70){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(73.964,144.757){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){30}}
\put(226.27,90.19){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(226.27,90.19){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(235.119,88.565){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){31}}
\put(203.12,89.59){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(203.12,89.59){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(206.114,81.098){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){32}}
\put(200.73,118.10){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(200.73,118.10){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(209.320,115.402){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){33}}
\put(218.61,139.68){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(218.61,139.68){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(226.052,144.734){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){34}}
\put(237.00,124.90){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(237.00,124.90){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(245.214,121.232){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){35}}
\put(224.51,62.25){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(224.51,62.25){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(229.249,54.602){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){36}}
\put(242.30,71.02){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(242.30,71.02){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(250.676,67.738){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){37}}
\put(222.75,30.16){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(222.75,30.16){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(217.357,37.365){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){38}}
\put(179.74,23.25){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(179.74,23.25){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(180.450,14.281){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){39}}
\put(193.16,38.32){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(193.16,38.32){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(199.279,31.718){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){40}}
\put(175.04,68.15){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(175.04,68.15){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(182.354,62.912){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){41}}
\put(167.34,45.20){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(167.34,45.20){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(166.168,36.275){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){42}}
\put(132.62,45.21){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(132.62,45.21){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(133.788,36.281){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){43}}
\put(124.94,68.16){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(124.94,68.16){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(117.616,62.923){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){44}}
\put(149.99,79.36){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(149.99,79.36){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(149.988,70.357){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){45}}
\put(172.93,127.59){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(172.93,127.59){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(179.385,133.858){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){46}}
\put(150.01,110.09){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(150.01,110.09){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(158.074,106.095){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){47}}
\put(127.09,127.59){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(127.09,127.59){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(120.635,133.862){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){48}}
\put(135.85,155.92){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(135.85,155.92){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(126.950,154.555){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){49}}
\put(164.18,155.91){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(164.18,155.91){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(173.074,154.546){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){50}}
\put(207.89,174.38){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(207.89,174.38){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(216.893,174.481){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){51}}
\put(181.36,180.78){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(181.36,180.78){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(186.772,187.970){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){52}}
\put(167.36,205.33){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(167.36,205.33){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(164.586,213.896){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){53}}
\put(186.42,219.16){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(186.42,219.16){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(192.733,225.577){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){54}}
\put(214.50,197.70){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(214.50,197.70){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(219.012,205.492){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){55}}
\put(251.21,148.61){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(251.21,148.61){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(259.531,152.040){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){56}}
\put(239.25,187.33){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(239.25,187.33){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(248.050,189.199){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){57}}
\put(236.81,207.84){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(236.81,207.84){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(242.806,214.549){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){58}}
\put(267.71,175.68){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(267.71,175.68){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(259.131,172.970){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){59}}
\put(260.70,130.54){\color[rgb]{0.902,0.902,0.902} \circle*{5}}
\put(260.70,130.54){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0} \circle{5}}
\put(269.466,128.511){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){60}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For example, the horizontal edge created by following code is good.

```
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(130.66,240.67)(150.02,240.69)(169.38,240.70)
```

But the following is not good:

```
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(60.78,187.36)(62.00,197.59)(63.22,207.82)
```

[image]

I know that converting to TikZ code might be better, but is there really no solution for qbezier (because adjusting too much would also result in a significant amount of work)?

Comment: you are printing  thousands of full stops `.` and hoping it looks OK, it looked quite OK on a  1990's dot  matrix printer, less so now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load also `pict2e`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(300,300)
\thicklines
\linethickness{1pt}
\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\qbezier(60.78,187.36)(62.00,197.59)(63.22,207.82)
[...]
\put(269.466,128.511){\color[rgb]{0.0,0.0,0.0}\makebox(0,0){60}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

The dots means that the missing part from your code is unchanged.

[image]

Comment: Nice!   I think it's great, butI am not quite sure why importing this package `pict2e` is enough to solve the problem.

Comment: @licheng It's enough, because `pict2e` has drivers for instructing PDF to draw the Bézier curves, rather than approximating them with small segments.